# Runtime too slow for minimax implementation (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, game-development

I'm writing a 3D tic tac toe game and I wanted to code an unbeatable ai. I tried to write a minimax function with alpha beta pruning since the search space for 3D tic-tac-toe is very large. However, despite this, my function seems to running indefinitely for a test case I made. Below is the code and the test case. P1 is signified by 1 and p2 by -1.

```
def generate_winning_lines(board):
    n = len(board)
    winning_lines = set()
        
    # Add lines in xy plane
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, z) for y in range(n)]) for x in range(n) for z in range(n)}
    
    # Add lines in yz plane
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, z) for y in range(n)]) for z in range(n) for x in range(n)}
    
    # Add lines in zx plane
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, z) for x in range(n)]) for z in range(n) for y in range(n)}
    
    # Add lines in x direction
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, z) for x in range(n)]) for y in range(n) for z in range(n)}
    
    # Add lines in y direction
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, z) for y in range(n)]) for x in range(n) for z in range(n)}
    
    # Add lines in z direction
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, z) for z in range(n)]) for x in range(n) for y in range(n)}
    
    # Add diagonal lines
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, x, x) for x in range(n)])}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, x, n-1-x) for x in range(n)])}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, n-1-x, x) for x in range(n)])}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, n-1-x, n-1-x) for x in range(n)])}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, x, y) for x in range(n)]) for y in range(n)}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(y, x, x) for x in range(n)]) for y in range(n)}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, x) for x in range(n)]) for y in range(n)}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, n -1 -x, y) for x in range(n)]) for y in range(n)}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(y, x, n -1 -x) for x in range(n)]) for y in range(n)}
    winning_lines |= {tuple([(x, y, n -1 -x) for x in range(n)]) for y in range(n)}

    return winning_lines
def victory_check(board, winning_lines):
    p1, p2 = None, None
    for line in winning_lines:
        values = [board[x][y][z] for x, y, z in line]
        if all(v == 1 for v in values):
            p1 = True, 1
        elif all(v == -1 for v in values):
            p2 = True, -1
        if p1 and p2:
            return True, 0
        elif p1:
            return p1
        elif p2:
            return p2
     return False, 0

def get_possible_moves(board):
    n = len(board)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                if board[i][j][k] == 0:
                    yield i,j,k

def best_move(board, winning_lines):
    n = len(board)
    best_score = float('-inf')
    move = (-1, -1, -1)
    for i,j,k in get_possible_moves(board):
        board[i][j][k] = -1
        curr_score = minimax(board, float('-inf'), float('inf'), False, winning_lines, 0)
        board[i][j][k] = 0
        if curr_score > best_score:
            move = (i,j,k)
            best_score = curr_score
    return move

def minimax(board, alpha, beta, to_max, winning_lines, depth):
    terminal = victory_check(board, winning_lines)
    if terminal[0]:
        return terminal[1]
    if to_max:
        best = float('-inf')
        for i,j,k in get_possible_moves(board):
            board[i][j][k] = -1
            score = minimax(board, alpha, beta, False, winning_lines, depth + 1)
            board[i][j][k] = 0
            best = max(score, best)
            alpha = max(alpha, best)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return best
    else:
        best = float('inf')
        for i,j,k in get_possible_moves(board):
            board[i][j][k] = 1
            score = minimax(board, alpha, beta, True, winning_lines, depth + 1)
            board[i][j][k] = 0
            best = min(score, best)
            beta = min(beta, best)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return best

# Testcase

board = [ # We want the function to return (0, 1, 1)
        [
            [1,-1,0],
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,1],
        ],
        [
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
        ],
        [
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
        ],
    ]
```

I've tried introducing a depth variable to stop the function from getting arbitrarily deep but it returns an incorrect move.

Comment: Please add `winning_lines` too :)

Comment: For readability, consider changing your nested list comprehensions `{tuple([(x, y, z) for y in range(n)]) for x in range(n) for z in range(n)}` to use `itertools.product` with `(x,y,z) for x,y,z in it.product(n, repeat=3)`. Much easier to read.